# Twitter stream latest tweets not working

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am trying to show the latest tweets on a webpage, but I am unsure of how to do it as I am very new to the twitter api, but here is what I have thus far.

```
function my_streaming_callback($data, $length, $metrics) {
  echo $data;
}

require '../tmhOAuth.php';
$tmhOAuth = new tmhOAuth(array(
  'consumer_key'    => 'key',
  'consumer_secret' => 'secret',
  'user_token'      => 'token',
  'user_secret'     => 'secret',
));

$method = 'http://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses//show/:id.json';
//not sure where I am supposed to get the :id from?

$params = array(
  //not sure what to put here, I would like to display the last 5 tweets
);

$tmhOAuth->streaming_request('POST', $method, $params, 'my_streaming_callback');
$tmhOAuth->pr($tmhOAuth);
```

I am using this https://github.com/themattharris/tmhOAuth to authenticate, and then interface with the twitter api, but I am finding it very confusing as all of this is very new to me.

So basically I would just like to try and get the latest tweets, any help would be GREATLY appreciated, as I need to get this done ASAP, thanx in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stream API returns you only the tweets posted **after** you connected. To get previous tweets you need to use general REST API method:  http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/statuses/show/:id

```
$tmhOAuth->request('GET', $tmhOAuth->url('1/statuses/show/$id'));
$tmhOAuth->pr(json_decode($tmhOAuth->response['response']));
```

where `$id` is the user's id.

Comment: Ok, how could I go about doing that? I am unsure of how to get the `:id`

Answer (score 0):

If you wish you can use [THIS](http://tweet.seaofclouds.com/) beautiful jQuery plugin. It do the some thing as you require. For more information visit http://tweet.seaofclouds.com/